# how can I hide empty cells in a table with bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know how I can hide empty cells in a table whilst using Bootstrap 3. Basically I am trying to create a calendar that is 6x6 table but I want to hide the borders of empty cells. I tried including the below in a css file (which I have located after bootstrap css file) but perhaps it's still being overriden because it's not working:

```
table {
empty-cells:hide;
}
```

Also is there any way I can do this dynamically because different calendar months don't always start from the same cell in the first row etc. Perhaps some jquery to target the empty cells and then remove their borders?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was being caused by `border-collapse: collapse;` which was overriding my css. Including `border-collapse: separate;` in my css resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply the style to the `<td>` elements:

```
table td {
  empty-cells: hide;
}
```

If you want to do it dynamically, then use a class to mark those empty cells that should have hidden borders:

```
table td.bashful {
  empty-cells: hide;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it still doesn't hide the empty cells. With regards to doing this dynamically, I know I must have a specific class for it but I was asking about the technical part of the problem - the only way I can think of doing this is say //loop through td elements
if ($(this).html() == "") { $(this).classed('.emptyCells') = true; } 
// apply css class when painting table
$('.emptyCells').classed('.bashful') = true; Is this a good approach?

Comment: @user3281466 well almost - you could just find the empty cells and `.addClass("bashful")`

Comment: ok, great. And why do you think bootstrap is still overriding the empty-cells:hide; property? I've read that you sometimes need to write the !important keyword but I am not actually sure how/where to use this ?

Comment: @user3281466 I don't know - you can use the browser DOM inspector to see where the table cells are picking up their styles.

Comment: hey, I just checked and it says that it's firstly picking up the borders from bootstrap and then it's also picking up my bit of css code. I'm assuming that if my css is after bootstrap then surely it should be overriding it?

Comment: I just saw after that it's also inheriting from the table class in bootstrap which is the cause of the problem. Do you know how I may override this?

Comment: @user3281466 well you can't really stop CSS rules, but you can override them with your own rules.

Comment: ok so the problem was being caused by border-collapse: collapse; which was overriding my css. Including border-collapse: separate; in my css resolved the issue. If you edit your question to include this then I will accept this as an answer. thanks for your help!